# left join optional table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

i try to select table `pep_posts` then left join with `pep_postmeta` but table `pep_postmeta` is optional mean if no data in table `pep_postmeta` , the result still can show.

below is my query but this query only show data if table `pep_postmeta` has data, this not what i want.

```
select p.*, pm.* 
from `pep_posts` p 
left join `pep_postmeta` pm 
  on pm.post_id=p.ID 
where p.post_parent='".$current_page_id."' and
     p.post_status='publish' and pm.meta_key='book_image'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a left join, if you reference the optional table in the `WHERE` clause, it will still filter out only the rows that have a value in that table. What you need to do is move the condition on `pm` to the `ON` clause where it won't remove rows, just set the values to `NULL`.

```
SELECT p.*, pm.* 
FROM `pep_posts` p 
LEFT JOIN `pep_postmeta` pm 
  ON pm.post_id=p.ID and pm.meta_key='book_image' 
WHERE p.post_parent='".$current_page_id."' AND
     p.post_status='publish'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your WHERE condition

```
and pm.meta_key='book_image'
```

If pep_postmeta have no data, pm.meta_key value in your selection will be NULL
So, you should remove this condtion or rewrite it to something like this

```
and (pm.meta_key='book_image' or pm.meta_key IS NULL)
```